# Crontab is running multiple instances of the same .py

Tags: python, linux, cron

I'm using a twitter auto retweet bot and sometimes after 20 minutes the bot stops and sometimes it doesn't stop. To fix this issue I'm using crontab to rerun the program every 20 minutes.

```
*/20 * * * * /home/TwitterFollowBot/bot.py 2>/tmp/twitterBot.log
```

but the issue is if the bot didn't stop within 20 minutes it's running 2X because crontab also starting another instance every 20 minutes. And this will keep happening if the bot doesn't stop. Sometimes it's running 10X which means it retweets more than the limit. So what I need to do is kill all/this bot.py every 19 minutes and on the 20th minute a fresh bot.py will run.

bot.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from TwitterFollowBot import TwitterBot
my_bot = TwitterBot("/home/TwitterFollowBot/config.txt")
my_bot.sync_follows()
my_bot.auto_rt("@SupStreamers", count=2200)
my_bot.auto_rt("@#SupportSmallStreamers", count=2200)
my_bot.auto_rt("@Small_Streamers", count=2200)
```

Comment: what about keeping a lock file that tells if the script is running or not?

Comment: This appears to be a classical [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why don't you, instead of trying to figure out how to kill your bot before it crashes, try to figure out why it sometimes crashes after 20 minutes in the first place? That would be more sensible *and* a better suited question for SO.

Comment: Do you think it will solve my issue? what if ti stops? I have to run it manually right? which mean I have to check the VPS every 20 minutes. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Phillip because of the twitter API system I think.
Sometimes it tries to re-tweet the same tweet over and again and then it crashes.

Comment: Trying to stop the programming from crashing is a programming problem. Monitoring it and restarting it when it does crash is a sysadmin problem. Fix your code first, then start worrying about the hosting. A sysadmin would suggest you add monitoring so you get alerts when the program is not running. A sysadmin would also suggest you run it as a daemon through systemd.

Answer (score 1):

Cron is not the right tool here. There are plenty of systems that monitor a process to ensure it is still up, and restart it if not - these include supervisor, systemd, monit, and upstart. Any of these would be a better fit.

Comment: Which one is the easiest one to use? because I have a very basic knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You put a controller at the start of your script, which reads what python scripts are currently active. If the same script is already running, you tell your script to do nothing.

I'm using Regex, you can use whatever you want if you dislike regex.

```
import os, commands, subprocess, re

def find(pat, string):
    match = re.search(pat, string)  # find function for searches below
    if match:
        return match.group()
    else:
        return None

allProcessIDs = os.popen('pgrep -lf python').read()
sameProcessID = find('\d{7} python YourApplicationName.py', allProcessIDs)
if sameProcessID:
    raise Systemexit
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So all I need yo do is copy and paste this code top of the python? do I need to put this above "#!/usr/bin/env python" or below this?

Comment: I get this error
root@ip-**************:/home/TwitterFollowBot# python bot.py
  File "bot.py", line 24

                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You put it below the shebang, just before your normal code. This is a snap from a code I have in production. If you have some issues pastebin your code and where you implemented it. Also do note that I use tabs instead of spaces. PEP8 hah..

Comment: Also do note pgrep is for *nix based systems. I assume you dont have windows because of crontab

Comment: it did not fix the multiple .py running issue.  :(

Comment: in your process list, does it show multiple bot.py?

Comment: in this line " sameProcessID = find('\d{7} python YourApplicationName.py', allProcessIDs) "  do I need to add the path of py as well? or just the name of py.